# Notify component that hosting tab was activated

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was thinking of a way to make a custom component aware of that the tab which hosts it was selected.
Let's say that's what I have:

```
<md-tab-group (selectChange)="activateTab($event)">
    <md-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
        <ng-template md-tab-label>
            <em>{{tab.label}}</em><span fxFlex></span><button class="md-button md-fab-close" (click)="removeTab(tab)"><md-icon md svgIcon="fd-close"></md-icon></button>
        </ng-template>
        <info-pane [viewBag]="tab.viewBag"></info-pane>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

The `InfoPaneComponent` has a method called `actualize` that should be called when the tab is activated.

The `selectChange` emits a `MdTabChangeEvent` that has tab's index and the `MdTab` itself, but I can't find a way to dig into it and get to the `InfoPaneComponent`. And I didn't find a proper way of calling that method without digging into `MdTab`, can someone give me any clue, please?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a @ViewChild property for the InfoPaneComponent  and then call that on SelectChange event by checking the tab index (if you have multiple tabs). Here is a reference of how to use @ViewChild 
http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/

Comment: I thought about it, but it implies creation of a subclass for `MdTab` and then using it instead, which I wanted to refrain, or there is another way?